# docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:/Program Files/Git/opt' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path

Tags: docker, laravel

Laravel9 を sail を使ってインストールしようとしていますが、エラーになってしまいます。

インストールしたい（これか作りたい）フォルダの場所に git-bash でアクセス
[Laravel公式の手順](https://readouble.com/laravel/9.x/ja/installation.html#laravel-and-docker)に従って、 `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash` を実行
※example-app は 003_myapp にしています

すると下記のようなエラーが発生しました

```
$ curl -s https://laravel.build/003_myapp | bash
docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:/Program Files/Git/opt' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.
See 'docker run --help'.

Please provide your password so we can make some final adjustments to your application's permissions.

bash: line 31: sudo: command not found

Thank you! We hope you build something incredible. Dive in with: cd 003_myapp && ./vendor/bin/sail up
```

Windows Subsystem for Linux 2（WSL2）が必要ということですが、下記の通り問題ないように思えます。

```
$ wsl --list --verbose
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
```

### [image: dockerの設定]

[image: dockerの設定]
どこから手を付けてよいのか分からず止まっています。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらのサイトを参考に作業したところ上手くいきました。
作業自体を Ubuntu　で行う必要がありました

[もう迷わない！Windows + Laravel Sail(Docker)で動作が遅くならない開発環境構築 Windows10 Home対応](https://zenn.dev/na9/articles/ffe7b884fee7d2)